# problems installing packages with npm

Tags: npm, npm-install, partition, disk-partitioning

i have a problem installing any packages with npm.
The console error are.

```
npm WARN rollback Rolling back serve-static@1.13.2 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/media/moshab97/W - L/prueba/node_modules/serve-static'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back mime@1.4.1 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/media/moshab97/W - L/prueba/node_modules/mime'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back send@0.16.2 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/media/moshab97/W - L/prueba/node_modules/send'
npm WARN rollback Rolling back express@4.16.4 failed (this is probably harmless): ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/media/moshab97/W - L/prueba/node_modules/express'
npm WARN prueba@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN prueba@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! code ENOSYS
npm ERR! errno -38
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! ENOSYS: function not implemented, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/media/moshab97/W - L/prueba/node_modules/.bin/mime'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/moshab97/.npm/_logs/2019-04-02T16_28_40_007Z-debug.log
```

I have partitioned my disk to have Windows and Linux, and part of a shared document partition is between windows and linux. If I try to install packages in that shared folder, it throws me the errors above, but if I make a project out of that shared folder it does not generate errors and installs correctly.

Comment: What packages are you trying to install? What was the script that provoked the error? What is the relevant content of your current directory?

Comment: Anything package, but i try install express, mongoose, request.

I just detected the error, to see if you have a solution.
I have partitioned my disk to have windows and linux, and part of a shared document partition between windows and linux; if I try to install packages in that shared folder, it throws me the errors above, but if I make a project out of that shared folder it does not generate errors and installs me correctly

Comment: That is relevant to the question - I added it as part of the latest edit.

Comment: All right.
In fact now that I was experimenting I realized that.
Thank you